# How cout distinguishes basic types?

Tags: c++, types, cout

Since my shifting from C to C++ I have a question on STL's formatting output. How ostreams tell one basic type from another?

In C with its printf and formatting strings it was pretty straightforward, but in C++ ostreams somehow distinguish basic types automatically. It puzzles me.

For example, in the following code,

```
int i;
float f;

std::cout << i << std::endl;
std::cout << f << std::endl;
```

how cout "knows" that **i** is an int and **f** is a float?

Comment: Streams have never had anything to do with the STL. You're thinking of the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler converts the operators to function calls.  So that

```
std::cout << i
```

becomes

```
operator<<(std::cout, i)
```

Somewhere buried deep in the bowels of the standard library headers there are function declarations (functionally equivalent to):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, int i);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, double d);
```

That is, `operator<<` is overloaded.  When the function call is made, the compiler chooses the function overload which is the best match to the arguments passed in.

In the case of `std::cout << i`, the `int` overload is chosen.  In the case of `std::cout<<d`, the `double` overload is chosen.

You can see function overloading in action fairly simply with a contrived example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int i) {printf("%d\n", i);}
void print(double d) {printf("%f\n", d);}

int main()
{
   int j=5;
   double f=7.7;

   print(j);
   print(f);
}
```

Producing the output:

```
5
7.700000
```

Try it for yourself: http://ideone.com/grlZl.

**Edit**:  As Jesse Good points out, the functions in question are member functions.  So really we have:

```
std::cout << i
```

becomes

```
std::cout.operator<<(i)
```

And in the headers there are declarations (equivalent to):

```
class ostream {
    ostream& operator<<(int i);
    ostream& operator<<(double d);
    ...
};
```

The same basic idea holds, however.

Comment: Not all `operator<<` are free functions, the `int` and `float` overloads are [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). `std::cout.operator<<(int i);`

Comment: @JesseGood: Good point.  So my example isn't quite factually correct.  It's still basically correct, and I feel that changing it to be perfect would obscure the main idea.  Not to mention trying to describe how `std::endl` is actually coded...

Comment: @Managu: Sure there is! It is generated at compile-time as an instantiation of the _class template_ `basic_ostream` :)

Answer (score 3):

There are operator<< overloads for each type (int, float etc).
The compiler will then choose the correct one at compile time.
In general, the operator<< have the form `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,  int number )`, where the function is a global function defined in the std namespace. You can overwrite the definition of this function by declaring it in your own namespace (this is done via Argument Dependent Lookup).

The fact the function returns a reference to the stream, means you can string them together. Just remember, whenever you see operator<<, it really is just a function call.

If you want to have a look, and you're using VS, open

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ostream.

There you'll find all the definitions if you're curious.

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution on the second argument to `operator<<`

Answer (score 1):

Function overloading is a form of compile-time polymorphism.  A simple example:

```
void times_two(int& x) { x *= 2; }
void times_two(double& x) { x *= 2; }

int i = 2;
double d = 2.5;

times_two(i);  // i now 4
times_two(d);  // d now 5.0
```

In the case of `std::ostream`s such as `std::cout`, the `operator<<()` functions overload in a similar way.  From the Standard Library shipped with GCC 3.4.4:

```
__ostream_type&
operator<<(int __n);

__ostream_type&
operator<<(double __f);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an overloaded ostream operator <<. In c++ you can overload a function name based on it's parameters. This is basically what's happening here. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/